# Javascript Objects - when filter, my object's keys become a list of ordered numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on filtered an object. The filtration works great but my object's keys are tansformed in an ordered list of key.

Here my original object:

```
5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a3
:
{addAt: 1534719398189, quantity: 1}

5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a5
:
{addAt: 1534719405264, quantity: 1}

5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a6
:
{addAt: 1534719412309, quantity: 1}

5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a7
:
{addAt: 1534719410266, quantity: 1}
```

after the filtering (minus one object filtered), my object is transformed as following:

```
0
:
"5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a3"
1
:
"5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a7"
2
:
"5b7973bdce3eb938a6de86a6"
```

Why my properties keys changes ?

Here what I have tried so far without success:

**method A ES6:**

```
var newState = Object.keys(state).filter((key, index) => {
    console.log("REMOVE_ARTICLE_REDUCER: " + "key: ", key + ", id: ", id); 
    return key !== id
});
```

**method B with lodash:**

```
newState= _.map(newState, function(object) {
    if (object.id !== id) return object;
});
```

**method C ES6:**

```
Object.filter = (obj, predicate) => 
    Object.keys(obj)
          .filter( key => predicate(obj[key]) )
          .reduce( (res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {} );
```

How cure this difficulty ? Any hint would be great,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in ***method A***, you're filtering an array of keys instead of the object itself, you'll have to change the filtered keys back to an object after you've done filtering them.

And in ***method B***, you are mapping the keys, not filtering them, so the unwanted keys will remain the resulting object with an `undefined` value.

In ***method C***, you're actually not making the same mistake as in method A (you are actually changing the keys back to an object), but the filtering won't work, because your passing the values to the predicate instead of the keys. Also you're altering the native object `Object` which is bad.

Here is how to do it:

**ES6:**

Using `filter` to filter out the keys, then `reduce` to transform them back into an object:

```
var newState = Object.keys(state).filter(key => key != id)
                     .reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key] = state[key], obj), {});
```

First, we start by filtering the keys of the object that we want to keep by doing `Object.keys(state)` which retrieves the keys and `.filter(key => key != id)` which filters out only those we need. Now, we are left with an array of the keys that we want, but we want the result to be an object, so we transform that array of wanted keys into an object by simply creating a new object (with the help of `reduce`), the new object will take values from the original object `state` for each wanted key.

**Lodash:**

Using [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pickBy):

```
var newState = _.pickBy(state, (value, key) => key != id);
```

`_.pickBy` does the same thing to objects that `_.filter` (or `Array#filter`) does to arrays.

Comment: can you please kindly add some comments to help us to decrypt your code, specifically the first code with the ES6 method ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you were returning only the key, not the object itself.
Try this:

```
Object.filter((item) => {
    return item.id !=== yourid
});
```